# Is it possible for a substance to be lighter than air in a liquid state?

Tags: air, density

*Is* there a substance while in a liquid state that will have a lower density than airs density while in a gas state.

Comment: I removed the tag "density of states" because this is not at all what that concept refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually a surprisingly deep question.

Our air  is composed of (mostly) diatomic molecules, and the lighter diatomics at that.The density of a (pure) substance is very closely linked with its atomic weight and therefore it's position on the periodic table. For this discussion we can ignore exceptions to this (because they are primarily in heavier elements) and focus only on basic principles. The state of a given bit of matter, in short, is determined by the relationship between the electromagnetic interactions between molecules of a substance and the amount of kinetic energy that the average molecule in that matter has.

If something's molecules have much more kinetic energy on average than than the electromagnetic potential energy between them, this will result in a gas. If they're more on the same level, we see a liquid, and if molecules have much more potential pulling them together than the kinetic energy can overcome, we see a solid.

In general, because of this principle, the molecules in a liquid will be much more tightly packed together than the molecules in a gas of the same substance. Steam floats in water, gaseous nitrogen floats in liquid nitrogen.

The air on earth is primarily made up of nitrogen, and it's density, as a gas, ends up being more determined by the amount of pressure that it's under, but no matter the pressure that a gas is under, it will always have a much lower density than any liquid, where the molecules are close enough to have a large amount of electromagnetic interaction between them.

I did a little bit of research and found the highest density gases that humans are aware of never rise above (at Standard temperature and pressure) a density of ~13 g/L.

Liquid Hydrogen, which would be the lightest liquid in the universe according to the principle I discussed earlier, has a density of 70.85 g/L. This is still about 6 times denser than the densest gas, which even if you were to bring it to low temperature or pressure, such that it is right on the line of condensing into liquid form, still never rises above ~15 g/L.

Unfortunately, we probably won't be able to find a liquid that floats in our air, but it would be super cool.

Answer (score 0):

No. The density of liquid hydrogen is $70.8 \frac {kg}{m^³}$, the density of air is $1.225 \frac  {kg}{m^3}$ so as you see there is still a large difference in density, even when you use the lighest element.